# Check if an address is within an area map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

The need I have is that a user (client) can put his/her address and to validate if it is within our delivery area.

Currently I have designed this layer on google maps:

https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1E3bcIm6Dy4icmTA4S-hEqOZeHpU

What is the technology that I use?

I just need an input text of a formulary to write the address and respond with an OK or a sorry.

All the information that I find are questions and solutions to calculate routes and only need to verify an address within an area.

Now I know as autofill and get save the address to verify. Now I just need to know how I can verify that direction in my area.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a sketch for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/zw6f78xk/

First the [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) was used to input an address, which gives you the location of the address

Then the [location is checked](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) whether it is inside the polygon.

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place.geometry.location, polygon)
```

Hope this helps.

`Update:`

But now because you already have the polygon on your google map, it is easy to modify its shape and retrieve its coordinates.
Just add `editable: true` to the polygon options then you can modify it manually and finally you can get the coordinates for example like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(evt) { 
    var pathArray = polygon.getPath().getArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++){
        console.log(pathArray[i].toUrlValue());
    };
});
```

So clicking on the polygon it logs its path.

`Update 2:`

Geocoding the typed (but not selected from the autocomplete) address.
https://jsfiddle.net/zw6f78xk/3/

Comment: Would you please provide the latest version API demo fiddle?

Comment: JSFiddle uses the latest API version. I added an alert to the script to show the API version:https://jsfiddle.net/fqugdh2z/