# Check if an address is in one of several polygons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Been a rabid consumer of Stack Overflow for many moons, but this is my first question so bear with me!

I know HTML & CSS but am not very JS literate, nor am I experienced in the Google Maps API.

I want my users to input an address using the Google Maps 'places' library and return a result as to whether or not the lat/long coordinates of that place fall within one of **three** predetermined polygons on the map.

Based on the location provided, the API would generate one of 3 messages:

- **If** the coordinate is outside all polygons **then** display msg 1
- **If** the coordinate is inside polygon 1 **then** display msg 2
- **If** the coordinate is inside **either** polygon 2 or 3, **then** display msg 3.

I found [this near-perfect-match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607189/check-if-an-address-is-within-an-area-map/39612364#39612364) for my need case which was well answered by [MKiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6298881/mkiss). The JS code is:

```
var map;
var geocoder; //Added on 27/09/2016
var marker;
var polygon;
var bounds;
window.onload = initMap;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: center,
        zoom: 14,
        scaleControl: true
    });
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); //Added on 27/09/2016
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(evt) { 
        bounds = map.getBounds();
    });
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: center
        });
        polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: area,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FFd000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        fillColor: '#FFd000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    polygon.setMap(map);    

    var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
        document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        marker.setMap(null);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(bounds.getSouthWest(), bounds.getNorthEast()); //Changed
        // removed newBounds = bounds;
          if (!place.geometry) {
                        geocodeAddress(input.value);//Added on 27/09/2016          
            //window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
          };
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setMap(map);
          newBounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          map.fitBounds(newBounds);
          if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place.geometry.location, polygon)){
            alert('The area contains the address');  
          } else {
            alert('The address is outside of the area.');  
          };
       });
}

//Added on 27/09/2016
//*************************
function geocodeAddress(addr) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': addr}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        var newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(bounds.getSouthWest(), bounds.getNorthEast());
          marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
          marker.setMap(map);
          newBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
          map.fitBounds(newBounds);
          if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(results[0].geometry.location, polygon)){
            alert('The area contains the address');  
          } else {
            alert('The address is outside of the area.');  
          };
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
}; 
//*************************

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(41.3899621, 2.1469796);
var area= [
{lat: 41.3749971 , lng: 2.1669979},
{lat: 41.3749569 , lng: 2.1683179},
{lat: 41.3759391 , lng: 2.1690059},
{lat: 41.3780967 , lng: 2.1652293},
{lat: 41.3777424 , lng: 2.1645641},
{lat: 41.380383 , lng: 2.1611738},
{lat: 41.3820333 , lng: 2.1634162},
{lat: 41.3837962 , lng: 2.1614313},
{lat: 41.3956283 , lng: 2.1772671},
{lat: 41.4000548 , lng: 2.1715379},
{lat: 41.3973829 , lng: 2.16156},
{lat: 41.3970609 , lng: 2.1603155},
{lat: 41.3981555 , lng: 2.158041},
{lat: 41.3990569 , lng: 2.1534061},
{lat: 41.400924 , lng: 2.1511316},
{lat: 41.4019541 , lng: 2.1492863},
{lat: 41.4015678 , lng: 2.1472263},
{lat: 41.400087 , lng: 2.1439648},
{lat: 41.4014068 , lng: 2.1419048},
{lat: 41.3997651 , lng: 2.1375704},
{lat: 41.3980911 , lng: 2.1330643},
{lat: 41.3957088 , lng: 2.1283007},
{lat: 41.3930689 , lng: 2.1241379},
{lat: 41.3883039 , lng: 2.1270561},
{lat: 41.3882556 , lng: 2.128129},
{lat: 41.3857442 , lng: 2.1296847},
{lat: 41.3831039 , lng: 2.130897},
{lat: 41.3805882 , lng: 2.1322328},
{lat: 41.3769615 , lng: 2.1339547},
{lat: 41.3761192 , lng: 2.1343651},
{lat: 41.3753413 , lng: 2.1350651},
{lat: 41.3751301 , lng: 2.1405369},
{lat: 41.3750193 , lng: 2.1458101},
{lat: 41.3747598 , lng: 2.1521402},
{lat: 41.374651 , lng: 2.1585345},
{lat: 41.3746349 , lng: 2.1606589},
{lat: 41.3747476 , lng: 2.1653795},
{lat: 41.3749971, lng: 2.1669979}
];
```

But am at a loss as to how to code the logic to deal with all three polygons.

I've constructed the three polygons [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uH_OUMtw10bO3wzmsSGpnm8phIbYyQhh&usp=sharing).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So if it is inside Polygon 1, you are displaying messages 2 and 3?

Comment: @Stev thanks for the question - i just edited my question which was slightly inaccurate. It now says **f the coordinate is inside either polygon 2 or 3, then display msg 3.**

Answer (score 2):

The following code alert if the address is inside of any of the given polygons.

(Replace `YOUR_GOOGLE_KEY` with your google key on index.html)

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="js-input" class="map__input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
    <div id="js-map" class="map"></div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.css

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}


.map__input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 280px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

index.js

```js
const myPolygons = [
  {
    name: 'Yellow Area',
    path: [ // You have to changes those values with lats and lngs of your polygon
      { lat: 11.0104601, lng: -74.8078690 },
      { lat: 11.0034337, lng: -74.7891669 },
      { lat: 11.022699, lng: -74.80161799 },
    ],
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FFd000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4,
    fillColor: '#FFd000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  },
  {
    name: 'Blue Area',
    path: [ // You have to changes those values with lats and lngs of your polygon
      { lat: 11.0194794, lng: -74.8504209 },
      { lat: 11.0131404, lng: -74.8276712 },
      { lat: 10.9946794, lng: -74.8395515 },
    ],
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: 'blue',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4,
    fillColor: 'blue',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  },
  {
    name: 'Green Area',
    path: [ // You have to changes those values with lats and lngs of your polygon
      { lat: 10.9772761, lng: -74.8134354 },
      { lat: 10.9933967, lng: -74.8183852 },
      { lat: 10.987963, lng: -74.78883119 },
    ],
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: 'green',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4,
    fillColor: 'green',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  },
];

function initMap() {
  let map;
  let marker;

  const createMap = ({ latitude, longitude, polygons, mapId, inputId }) => {
    const center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapId), { center, zoom: 14, scaleControl: true });

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: center });

    const createGooglePolygons = ({ name, ...polygon }) => {
      const newPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon(polygon);
      newPolygon.setMap(map);

      return { name, polygon: newPolygon };
    }

    const googlePolygons = polygons.map(createGooglePolygons);

    const input = document.getElementById(inputId);

    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    const onAutocompleteChange = () => {
      const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      const location = place.geometry.location;
      const poly = google.maps.geometry.poly;

      if (!place.geometry) return alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");

      marker.setPosition(location);
      marker.setMap(map);

      const isLocationInsidePolygon = ({ polygon }) => poly.containsLocation(location, polygon);

      const matchedPolygon = googlePolygons.find(isLocationInsidePolygon);

      if (!matchedPolygon) return alert('The address does not match any valid area');

      alert(`The ${matchedPolygon.name} contains the address`);
    };

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onAutocompleteChange);
  }

  createMap({
    latitude: 10.9939751, //Put your origin latitude here
    longitude: -74.8069332, //Put your origin longitude here
    polygons: myPolygons,
    mapId: 'js-map',
    inputId: 'js-input'
  })
};

window.onload = initMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the polygons separately and alter the logic to test for whether the location is within each polygon or both. I am not familiar with javascript but here is an example using you code that should get you started (maybe someone more familiar will tidy it up):

```
var map;
var marker;
var polygon;
var bounds;
window.onload = initMap;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: center,
        zoom: 14,
        scaleControl: true
    });
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(evt) { 
        bounds = map.getBounds();
    });
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: center
        });
        polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: area1,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FFd000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        fillColor: '#FFd000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
        polygon2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: area2,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#00ffe1',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        fillColor: '#00ffe1',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    polygon1.setMap(map);   
  polygon2.setMap(map);

    var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
        document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        marker.setMap(null);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        newBounds = bounds;
          if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
          };
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setMap(map);
          newBounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          map.fitBounds(newBounds);
          if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place.geometry.location, polygon1)){
            if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place.geometry.location, polygon2)){
            alert('The address is inside polygon1 and 2');  
          } else {
            alert('The address is inside polygon1');  
          }  
          } else {
          if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place.geometry.location, polygon2)){
            alert('The address is inside polygon2');  
          } else {
            alert('The address is outside of the area.');  
          };
          }
       });
}

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(41.3899621, 2.1469796);
var area1= [
{lat: 41.3749971 , lng: 2.1669979},
{lat: 41.3749569 , lng: 2.1683179},
{lat: 41.3759391 , lng: 2.1690059},
{lat: 41.3780967 , lng: 2.1652293},
{lat: 41.3777424 , lng: 2.1645641},
{lat: 41.380383 , lng: 2.1611738},
{lat: 41.3820333 , lng: 2.1634162},
{lat: 41.3837962 , lng: 2.1614313},
{lat: 41.3956283 , lng: 2.1772671},
{lat: 41.4000548 , lng: 2.1715379},
{lat: 41.3973829 , lng: 2.16156},
{lat: 41.3970609 , lng: 2.1603155},
{lat: 41.3981555 , lng: 2.158041},
{lat: 41.3990569 , lng: 2.1534061},
{lat: 41.400924 , lng: 2.1511316},
{lat: 41.4019541 , lng: 2.1492863},
{lat: 41.4015678 , lng: 2.1472263}];
var area2= [
{lat: 41.3973829 , lng: 2.16156},
{lat: 41.3970609 , lng: 2.1603155},
{lat: 41.3981555 , lng: 2.158041},
{lat: 41.3990569 , lng: 2.1534061},
{lat: 41.400924 , lng: 2.1511316},
{lat: 41.4019541 , lng: 2.1492863},
{lat: 41.4015678 , lng: 2.1472263},
{lat: 41.400087 , lng: 2.1439648},
{lat: 41.4014068 , lng: 2.1419048},
{lat: 41.3997651 , lng: 2.1375704},
{lat: 41.3980911 , lng: 2.1330643},
{lat: 41.3957088 , lng: 2.1283007},
{lat: 41.3930689 , lng: 2.1241379},
{lat: 41.3883039 , lng: 2.1270561},
{lat: 41.3882556 , lng: 2.128129},
{lat: 41.3857442 , lng: 2.1296847},
{lat: 41.3831039 , lng: 2.130897},
{lat: 41.3805882 , lng: 2.1322328},
{lat: 41.3769615 , lng: 2.1339547},
{lat: 41.3761192 , lng: 2.1343651},
{lat: 41.3753413 , lng: 2.1350651},
{lat: 41.3751301 , lng: 2.1405369},
{lat: 41.3750193 , lng: 2.1458101},
{lat: 41.3747598 , lng: 2.1521402},
{lat: 41.374651 , lng: 2.1585345},
{lat: 41.3746349 , lng: 2.1606589},
{lat: 41.3747476 , lng: 2.1653795},
{lat: 41.3749971, lng: 2.1669979}
];
```